# After decimal precision difference same query on redshift vs mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that I run on MySQL and redshift. The same query gives different results after the decimal.

The result field is calculated by division of two columns. Both those columns are defined as an integer.

```
on MySQL - int(11) default 0
on RedShift - integer default 0
```

[image]

Why am I getting two different values for the same query on Redshift vs MySQL?
I use the column in a report which at the end shows 2 values after the decimal, the redshift values are being truncated and not rounded up.

Can anyone please give any input regarding this?

Comment: 'In division performed with /, the scale of the result when using two exact-value operands is the scale of the first operand plus the value of the div_precision_increment system variable (which is 4 by default). For example, the result of the expression 5.05 / 0.014 has a scale of six decimal places (360.714286).' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div

Comment: @P.Salmon I need to get proper values like mysql in Redshift, How can i achieve this?

Comment: @SuccessMaharjan Simply change the [`div_precision_increment`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_div_precision_increment) setting.

Comment: Erm.. the mysql values are correct in mysql terms. I don't know redshift but you could search for redshift integer division (or wait for someone who does know redshift to respond)

Comment: @Progman to what (how does redshift handle integer division?)

Comment: @SuccessMaharjan Do you want the values in MySQL the same as in redshift (around 12 decimal places) or do you want the values in redshift the same as in MySQL (4 decimal places)?

Comment: I want the values in redshift the same as in MySQL. Is there some kind of setting I can manipulate to get this or I can do this in some other way?

Comment: Any please please provide any input.